# How TreeSet works internally and stores custom object?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

class People implements Comparable {

```
private String name;

People(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "People [name=" + name + "]";
}
```

}

public class TestTreeSet {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Set<People> set=new TreeSet<>();
    People p1=new People("ABC");
    People p2=new People("DEF");
    People p3=new People("CBD");
    People p4=new People("ABC");
    
    set.add(p1);
    set.add(p2);
    set.add(p3);
    set.add(p4);
    
    System.out.print(set.size());
    
}
```

}

I am failed to understand how output is 1? Here I am storing 4 different object with 3 different values.
How it is storing only one object?

Comment: Since your compareTo always returns 0 it thinks all of the people are equal.  Since TreeSet is unique and sorted, it ignores the subsequent adds.

Comment: Your `compareTo` method always return zero, which means, all objects of this type are equal. Since a set does not store duplicates, it can’t have more than one of those always-equal objects.

Comment: `compareTo` returns always 0, means all objects are equal, so size is 1

Comment: You have to actually implement the compareTo method. By returning 0 all the time every single instance of this class equals another. Simly compare the "name" of this to the "name" of o and return the value.

Comment: You're also getting a ton of warnings, and you should pay attention to them.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually implement the "compareTo" method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
     if  (o instanceof People) {
         return ((People) o).name.compareTo(this.name);
     } else {
         return 1;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Don’t return `1` for wrong inputs. That violates the `Comparable` contract and is in no way helpful for wrong callers. The class should implement `Comparable<People>`, to have a `People` parameter type in the first place. For pre-generics code, the method should unconditionally cast to `People`, as it is impossible to compare it to something else and a `ClassCastException` is the best response to an argument of the wrong type.